# Verify if selenium tests are running on real devices or emulators

Tags: java, appium, emulators

If I use any cloud provider (eg SauceLabs, AWS Device Farm etc) for testing my native android and iOS apps, is there a way to determine if the test was being run on a real device or an emulator.

I need this check to verify the authenticity of the results. My appium code is written in Java. Is there any library or method I can call that verifies if the test is being run on a real device or an emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any library existence, but from the official SauceLabs response: one can use [TestObject](https://testobject.com/) to utilize real devices and [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) main resource to conduct testing on emulators/simulators. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the device lists for [AWS DeviceFarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/devices.html), [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/devices), and [SauceLabs TestObject](https://help.testobject.com/docs/general-reference/devices/). I have worked with each and they all accept a device identifier (defined in desired capabilities or via command line param). You get this Name or ID by picking from a list that clearly labels if it is a real device. I haven't found/looked for any emulators/simulators in my use of the products so I can't say if they even have them.